# Is there a transactional java key-value store that is embeddable and allows you to overwrite an object without first deleting it

Tags: java, nosql, key-value

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
 db.createDbIfNotExists("/some/file");

 db.doInTransaction(new DbTransaction() {
     public void do() {

         for(KeyValue kv : listOfKvs) {
            ...some code that might fail...
            db.save(kv.getKey(), kv.getObject());
         }
     }  
 }
```

If any keys already exist, I want the new object to overwrite the old object at that key. I don't want to have to load it and delete it or load and update it.

If during the transaction my code throws an exception, I want the writes to rollback.

It needs to be able to write 500,000 objects of less that 1k each in around 2/3 minutes.

Thanks in advance.

Tom

Comment: Redis (http://redis.io) and Voldemort (http://project-voldemort.com) are both key/value and if I recall correctly, can update without loading. You might want to check them out (I commented just in case you weren't aware of them, I have just used Redis for a small cache database).

Answer (score 0):

Tom:

Redis is your best bet.  I have used it extensively and it is a data structure server (not to be confused with a database server) that has eventual consistency.  It is in memory with a backing file store and it is blazing fast.  More details at redis.io.  The command set is at http://redis.io/commands  has transaction support as well  http://redis.io/topics/transactions

Supports multiple languages.  A java client is available at https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis

Answer (score 0):

Try Scalien, it has Java drivers, replicates consistently and supports ACID transactions.
http://scalien.com/products/